# What is palindromic DNA?

Tags: dna-rna

What is palindromic DNA and why isn't every complementary strand palindromic?

I know AGCT is palindromic, but what is an example of a strand that isn't?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be more about biology than pure chemistry. Better move to Biology.SE

Comment: It came from a biochem course. I was eavesdropping in some friends when they were studying.

Comment: This is a chemistry question, not a biology question.  DNA is a complex heteropolymer and whether or not comething is a palindrome can affect the polymer's reactivity and behavior.  Also, since when have questions needed to be about "pure" chemistry to be on topic around here? :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A palindromic stretch of DNA is a strand whose reverse complement is itself.  So `5'-AAAT-3'` is not palindromic.  It's reverse complement is `5'-ATTT-3'`.  Those two pieces of DNA are not identical.  However, `5'-GGATCC-3'` is palindromic, because the reverse complement is identical.

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with the complementarity (of the other strand).

Try this to figure out whether some sequences are palindromic:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def is_palindromic(seq):
    translation_table = str.maketrans('ACGT', 'TGCA')
    translation = seq.translate(translation_table)
    #print(seq, translation[::-1])
    return seq == translation[::-1]

is_palindromic('GATTACA')
```